# JQuery :last-child encapsulating parent of nested element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
//'[popup]' hook nested at random depths, using <ul> or <ol>, no classes or id's
<ol>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Foo
        <ol>
            <li>[popup]Bar</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I wish to target the `[popup]` hook, and give its `<li>` classes of popup, pop/n. I then wish to give its parent `(Foo)<li>` different classes of arrow, arr/n.

Here is the code:

```
var num = 0;

//Find [popup] instances, increment the number
$("li:contains('[popup]') li:last-child").each(function() {
    var nextnumber = num++;

    //add a general and a unique class to the list item containing the hook
    $(this).addClass('popup' + ' ' + 'pop' + nextnumber);

    //Get the parent list item, and give it general and unique classes also.
    $thisArrow = $(this).parent().parent();
    $thisArrow.addClass('arrow' + ' ' + 'arr' + nextnumber);

});
```

That is working no problem for targets nested one level deep, but not beyond that. When presented with a list where the target is nested two levels deep, the following occurs:

```
<ol>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li class="popup pop1 arrow arr1">Blah
        <ol>
            <li class="arrow arr0">Foo
                <ol>
                    <li class="popup pop0">[popup]Bar</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow arr2">Foo
                <ol>
                    <li class="popup pop2">[popup]Bar</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

You can see that, once the last (always the last occurance in the list) :last-child element was reached, somehow its parent's parent was given the classes for both target and parent, *then* the classes were added to it itself.

If anyone could point out my error, I'd be very grateful.

(I have tried `.parents().eq(1);` instead of `.parent().parent()` to the same result.)

Comment: Could you try to post the result you wanted, so we can compare it to what you got. Im a little confused of what you want to achieve - created an JsFiddle with your source http://jsfiddle.net/Jg9kv/

Comment: @Marco Apologies - actual use case here. Section A is what I want, Section D is what is happening when the target is nested further than one level.

http://databizsolutions.ie/contents/page.php?v=35&u=admin-videos#d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure of the arrow thing, but I think your main problem was that nested li content would also get targeted by the :contains

testing on the textual content for "beginning with [popup]" may help.

```
var num = 0;

//Find [popup] instances, increment the number
$("li:contains('[popup]')").each(function() {    
    if($(this).text().indexOf("[popup]")==0){
    var nextnumber = num++;
    $(this).addClass('popup' + ' ' + 'pop' + nextnumber);
}

});​
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/r3wK4/

DO tell me if I didn't understand the problem :-)

Comment: That looks great, +1 as well as I wasn't aware of indexOf - solved the problem!